# UnboundLocalError on local variable with two def() functions

Tags: python, function, global-variables

I am receiving the error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'locs' referenced before assignment
```

I did read in other posts that the solution to this is to use `global locs` after I define the function. However, there are two `def()` functions in which `locs =` appears. I've tried inserting `global locs` under one of the def functions and running, and have also ran the code with `global locs` defined in both functions, but receive the same error in each case.

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model2.py", line 107, in <module>
    main()
  File "model2.py", line 94, in main
    if not locs:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'locs' referenced before assignment
```

**Relevant Code**:

```
def extract_features(img_path):
  #  global locs #tried it here and got the same error
    X_img = face_recognition.load_image_file(img_path)
    locs = face_locations(X_img, number_of_times_to_upsample = N_UPSCLAE)
    if len(locs) == 0:
        return None, None
    face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(X_img, known_face_locations=locs)
    return face_encodings, locs

def predict_one_image(img_path, clf, labels):
    #global locs #tried it here with same error
    face_encodings, locs = extract_features(img_path)
    if not face_encodings:
        return None, None
    pred = pd.DataFrame(clf.predict_proba(face_encodings),
                        columns = labels)
    pred = pred.loc[:, COLS]
    return pred, locs

 print("classifying images in {}".format(input_dir))
    for fname in tqdm(os.listdir(input_dir)):
        img_path = os.path.join(input_dir, fname)
        try:
            pred, locs = predict_one_image(img_path, clf, labels)
        except:
            print("Skipping {}".format(img_path))
        if not locs:
            continue
        locs = \
            pd.DataFrame(locs, columns = ['top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'])
        df = pd.concat([pred, locs], axis=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Am I inserting `global locs` in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with `global`/`local` variables **nor** with the functions at all.

It is simply because of the `try/except` block:

```py
        try:
            pred, locs = predict_one_image(img_path, clf, labels)
        except:
            print("Skipping {}".format(img_path))
        if not locs:
            continue
```

Let's assume that `predict_one_image` does indeed raise an exception. This means neither `pred` nor `locs` will get to be defined. After that, the `except` block simply prints and the `if not locs` will fail.

There are 2 easy ways you can fix this. Either initialize `locs` to `None` in case the call will fail:

```
        try:
            locs = None
            pred, locs = predict_one_image(img_path, clf, labels)
        except:
            print("Skipping {}".format(img_path))
        if not locs:
            continue
```

Or, simply because you want to `continue` if `locs` is not defined (as I understand from the code), put the `continue` statement in the `except`:

```
        try:
            pred, locs = predict_one_image(img_path, clf, labels)
        except:
            print("Skipping {}".format(img_path))
            continue
```